# Replace ChildActionExtensions.Action with a ViewComponent?

Tags: asp.net-core-viewcomponent, child-actions

I've had no problem replacing "ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction" with a "ViewComponent", but I haven't figured out how to replace the (arguably simpler) "ChildActionExtensions.Action".  I just want to return some HTML, not a view.  I'm sure this is trivial, but for whatever reason this has me stymied.

Thanks in advance.